# Xcode Instruments - "This instrument does not support OSX"

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, instruments

I am trying to make some performance analysis with Instruments (XCode 7.2), but when I choose `Core Animation` instrument, it shows just the message "*This instrument does not support OSX*". I am running El Capitan (10.11.3). What am I doing wrong? How else, if not through OSX, am I supposed to run it?

[image: The error message + disabled "record" button]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This message means, that instrument may be used only for analysis of iOS application, not OS X one. There is no way to run it to analyze OS X app.

Edit: Just checked, and `Core Animation` instrument doesn't work with iOS Simulator too. You should use real device to able to analyze iOS application.

Comment: Thanks for response! Unfortunately I am trying to analyse iOS app, as you can see from the selected device in the top of the screenshot... Any idea?

Comment: Did you try to connect real iOS device? From your screenshot it looks like you are trying to analyze app on Simulator. Never use simulator with instruments, because results will be inaccurate.

Comment: I am trying to use my iPad, but I can't get the Instruments to use it. I can run my app on it, but Instruments just asks: "Enable this device for development? This will open Xcode and enable this device for development". Then I hit Open Xcode, nothing else happens and I still can use just the simulator in Instruments...

Comment: I've just updated my answer. You definitely need to use real device. I suggest to create another question about your problem with "enable this device for development" alert.